# how to measure page request time in milliseconds in a rails project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

New to rails, want to test the time it takes for a given page to render in milliseconds.

Where in the request pipeline do I do this? (start and stop the time, and output to the page)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you develop with WeBRICK or Mongrel, you should see this in the console:

```
Rendered layouts/application.html.erb (7.1ms)
Rendered members/index.html.erb within layouts/authed (184.8ms)
Completed 200 OK in 402ms (Views: 185.8ms | ActiveRecord: 26.2ms)
```

As you can see it says how long the request took to process the pages.

Comment: i see thanks, out of curiousity, 402ms is allot, what's going on there? hehe

Comment: @Blankman - It's just a development app, that happens to be doing way too many queries and processing to make the page.